# Mbp 15 retina early 2013-waiting for disks to reappear

Tags: macbook-pro, logicboard

I have a mbp 15 early 2013 model. It was running smoothly until yesterday suddenly it passed out with a folder question mark screen. so I went to recovery because I can't boot up. In the startup disk I can't find my ssd and in disk utility can't first aid my ssd and even can't erase my ssd to perform a fresh install.. when tried erasing in terminal it shows up the error waiting for disks to reappear.. so I think that ssd is working fine because it shows up on the disk utility, so this might be a controller problem in which in my case I don't have a hard drive cable, instead I think it's part of the logic board where ssd has to be plugged.. suggest me a solution.. Sorry for my explanation if it's bad.. I'm very much worried  as of now..

My question is different.. the apple genius couldn't figure out whether it's logic board or ssd.. because both are functioning properly in diagnosis.

how it is different.. I cant able to format using gparted.. so by using terminal I tried pdisk commands and was able to create and write partitions.. so does it conclude that ssd is still working.. if so what could have been the error

Comment: Drives appearing in Disk Utility is *not* an indication that your SSD is "working fine."  Chances are, your SSD failed.

Comment: ssd is able to write partitions in pdisk terminal . does that conclude ssd is in working state

reply asap